# Client error "Error: documentMatches needs a document" when removing an element from an array by index

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I'm seeing an error when I remove an element from an array in a collection. I'm removing the element by index.

What's weird is that the server code works but in the console I see an error "Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/patterns/update' Error: documentMatches needs a document".

I've spent ages trying to work out what the problem is and I'm stumped! See the code below for a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

(The only references I can find to this error don't seem relevant - I think this poster was identifying elements by attributes not index:
[Removing an object from an array inside a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948990/removing-an-object-from-an-array-inside-a-collection). And this post seems to relate to Angular, which I'm not using, and the question doesn't seem to have been answered: [Minimongo errors when I try to update a document containing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660541/minimongo-errors-when-i-try-to-update-a-document-containing-an-array))

Any ideas why the query might fail on the client but not the server? The error happens at the point when I pull the element from the array with

```
Patterns.update({_id: pattern_id}, {$pull : {"my_array" : null}});
```

Full code:

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Array test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">

  <p>Values in the array: {{array}}</p>
  <button class="add">Add item to array</button>
  <button class="remove">Remove item from array</button>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Patterns = new Mongo.Collection('patterns');
if (Patterns.find().fetch().length == 0)
{
  Patterns.insert({name: "My document", my_array: [0] });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.helpers({
    array: function () {
      return Patterns.find().fetch()[0].my_array;
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button.add': function () {
      pattern_id = Patterns.find().fetch()[0]._id;
      var new_value = Patterns.findOne(pattern_id).my_array.length;
      Patterns.update({_id: pattern_id}, {$push: {my_array: new_value}});
    },
    'click button.remove': function() {
      pattern_id = Patterns.find().fetch()[0]._id;
      var index = Patterns.findOne(pattern_id).my_array.length -1;
      var obj = {};
      obj["my_array." + index ] = "";
      Patterns.update({_id: pattern_id}, {$unset : obj});

      // THIS LINE CAUSES THE CONSOLE ERROR
      Patterns.update({_id: pattern_id}, {$pull : {"my_array" : null}});
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: Could you show the contents of your Patterns document right before you try to execute the update? Particularly the contents of my_array.

Comment: my_array is initially [0]. Clicking "Add item to array" appends a new value, incremented, so it will become [0,1,2] etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering a current limitation of Minimongo, that is mentioned [in the source here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/minimongo/modify.js#L370)

```
    // XXX Minimongo.Matcher isn't up for the job, because we need
    // to permit stuff like {$pull: {a: {$gt: 4}}}.. something
    // like {$gt: 4} is not normally a complete selector.
    // same issue as $elemMatch possibly?
```

However if you check your collection after that exception you will see that the item has been removed from your array.  This would have happened on the server side (with the real MongoDB, then synchronised back with your client side collection), as this error is only impacting the client side latency compensation operation on the client collection, which is then corrected when the update arrives from the server.

My suggestion given that you are encountering minimongo limitations would be to move your updates into meteor methods where you always interact  mongodb on the server, [though you will need to add stub methods to handle any latency compensation you require on the client.](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/latency-compensation/)

Comment: Thank you!

In my project code, my updates are in meteor methods but they run on both client and server to enable optimistic UI (at least, that's my understanding of how it works, but I'm still fairly new to Meteor).

Perhaps I can use a try / catch to prevent the client from showing an error. That way I'm still running the same functions on client and server, and it should work if Minimongo is ever updated. If that doesn't work, I'll split into two functions as you suggest.

Comment: In the end I wrapped the code in an if(Meteor.isServer){} block to avoid errors on the client caused by the previous line which sets the element to null before it is pulled. (This seems to be the only way to remove elements by index, but it's a two-step process)